# stuck with my small code in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have problem with the following code:

```
.
.
.

a=zeros(1000,ctimes);
a1=zeros(1000,ctimes);
hold all

for i=num1:num2;
colors=Lines(i);
switch phantom
   case 1    
path=['E:\filename\']; 
path1=['E:\filename2\']; 


n=['S',num2str(emt),'_',num2str(i),'.m'];
d=load([path,name]);
a(:,i)=complex(d(:,2),d(:,3)));


n1=['S',num2str(emt),'_',num2str(i),'.m'];
d1=load([path1,name1]);
a1(:,i)=complex(d1(:,2),d1(:,3)));
```

the problem is that `a(:,i)` can not be defined. while there is no problem or with `complex(d1(:,2),d1(:,3)))` , can any expert body help me plz?!

thank you ...

Comment: What do you mean by "can not be defined"? What error are you getting? Could this be something to do with the fact that you are building name strings called `n` and `n1` and then trying to use name strings called `name` and `name1`?

Comment: -1: a) how is the question title related to your problem? 2) can you provide a [short, self contained, correct, example](http://sscce.org/)? 3) without knowing the dimensions of `d` or what values `num1`, `num2` or `ctimes` take on, it is very hard to debug your code-snippet. 4) I suspect that your output of `complex` does not match `a(:,i)`.

Comment: I mean that when I put a(:,i) in Command window I get Error in ==> lab at 57
a(:,i)=20*log10(abs(complex(data(:,2),data(:,3)))); Im sure that 20*log10(abs(complex(data(:,2),data(:,3)))) is correct cause when I put it in command window it works well

Comment: What is the value of `i` when this problem occurs? What is `num1:num2`? If, by chance, `num2<num1`, the loop will not execute at all and `a(:,i)` will indeed have no sensible value. I am assuming that there is an `end` statement somewhere in your code... Please take @Schorsch's comment to heart and make a SSCE so we can reproduce (and thus debug) your error. Your report of the error is still unclear: "==> lab at 57". What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are forming your file name correctly? You are doing something to create a variable `n`, but using a variable `name` when you form the path. Here are some recommended debugging steps:

1) make sure the file path is formed correctly:

```
filePath = fullfile(path, name);
disp(filePath);
```

The `fullfile` function concatenates elements of a file path & name, and takes care of using the right file path separator (good for portable code, stops you having to remember to add a `/` or `\` to the end of a file path, etc).

2) check that `d` is loaded correctly:

```
clear d;
d = load(filePath);
disp(size(d));
```

3) check the size of the complex quantity you compute before assigning it to `a(:,i)`:

```
temp = complex(d(:,2), d(:,3));
disp(size(temp));
```

By the time you have done these things, you should have found your problem (the dimensions of `temp` should be `[1000 1]` to match the size of `a(:,i)`, of course).

As an aside, you should avoid using `i` as a variable name, especially when you are using complex numbers, since its built-in value is `sqrt(-1)`. Thus, `c = a + i * b;` would create a complex number (a,b) and put it into c - until you change the meaning of `i`. A simple solution is to use `ii`. The same is true for `j`, by the way. It is one of the unfortunate design decisions in Matlab that you can overwrite built in values like that...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replpy, will explain more. i is loop i=num1:num2; so nothing to do with sqrt(-1)